# Angular 6: display information about chosen dropdown-item on the same page

Tags: angular, angular6

I'm very new to Angular and I'm struggling with getting another component displayed on the same page. The idea is to choose smth from a dropdown menu and then get information about it below the dropdown *on the same page*. *Nothing should be displayed while no option from the menu is chosen*.

```
<div>
 <mat-form-field>
  <mat-select placeholder="Choose cat" [(value)]="selected">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let cat of cats" [value]="cat.name">
        {{cat.name}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
 </mat-form-field>
</div> 

<div *ngIf=[selected]>
 <app-animals-table [value]="cat"></app-animals-table>
</div>
```

Here, AnimalsTable component should take an input parameter *value* and display the information about the cat from the dropdown menu. Everything seems to work except that I can't find correct syntax for the if-statement and therefore can't display table *only when* item from the dropdown is chosen.

Comment: `*ngIf="selected"`try this, ngIf doesn't need brackets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned you have to remove the `[]` from the ngIf.

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-select [(value)]="selected">
   <mat-option>None</mat-option>
   <mat-option value="option1">Option 1</mat-option>
   <mat-option value="option2">Option 2</mat-option>
   <mat-option value="option3">Option 3</mat-option>
 </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>

<div *ngIf="selected">You selected: {{selected}}</div>
```

A working example can be found in this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ifnrak?file=app%2Fselect-value-binding-example.html)